# Increase number on button click

Tags: javascript, onclick, integer

I'm trying to make an application with JSON data for a frisbee tournament. I'm now working on a page where you can view and edit the scores from a match. It should be possible to increase or decrease the score of either of the two teams. It looks like this:

[image: Team #1: + / -, Team #2: + / -]

I skipped some parts from the code to make it easier to read. This is the relevant code:

```
gamePage: function(data){

    var score1 = parseInt(data.team_1_score),
        score2 = parseInt(data.team_2_score);

    var html = '',

    html_pool_open = '<section class="new_page">';
    html = html + html_pool_open;

    var html_pool_top = '<div class="game">';
    html = html + html_pool_top;

    var html_team_1 = '<div class="name">'+data.team_1.name+'</div>'
             + '<div class="score score_team1">'
                + '<a href="#" onclick="" ><img src="/images/plus.png"/></a>'
                + '<span>'+score1+'</span>'
                + '<a href="#" onclick="SCORE_APP.tools.minusOne()"><img src="/images/minus.png"/></a>'
             + '</div></div>';
```

The score between the span must be increased or decreased `onclick`

```
    html = html + html_team_1;

    x$('#content').html(html);
}
```

I'm not allowed to do it with jQuery, so vanilla JavaScript only please.

Comment: "x$('#content').html(html);" ?? why is there a "x" ?

Comment: apparently that's whatever is replacing jquery

Comment: I'm using xui.js for dom manipulation thats why

Comment: Exactly what part are you having trouble with; triggering your `adjustScore` function (or whatever you're calling it), or updating the html appropriately?

Comment: What happens if you use `data.team_1_score++` in the onclick of the plus sign?

Comment: @Rhyono No doesn't work. I want to know what the onclick function is to manipulate the score between the span.

Comment: If you gave the span an id, you could make the onclick do something like (I'll do this as pure JS): `document.getElementById("score1span").innerHTML = data.team_1_score+1` That would not update the score variable (which is what my prior example does), but it would update it visually.

Comment: After I have in- or decreases the int and I click on the Oke button, I have to make a post to an API to update the score. so the value of the int has to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I would do somethig like this:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ucIliju/1/edit)**

```
var data = {
  team_1_score: 42,
  team_2_score: 6,
  team_1 : {name:'Beast Amsterdam'},
  team_2 : {name:'Amsterdam Money Gang'}
};

var SCORE_APP = {

  tools : {
    setScore : function( i, pm ){
       var currScore= parseInt( data['team_'+ i +'_score'] , 10);
       if(currScore=='0' && pm=='dn') return; // prevent -1 score
       var newScore = data['team_'+ i +'_score'] += (pm=='up'? 1 : -1);
       document.getElementById('team_'+ i +'_score').innerHTML = newScore;      
    }
  },

  game : {
    gamePage : function(data) {
      var html = '<section class="new_page">';      
      for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
          html += '<div class="game"><div class="name">'+ data['team_'+i].name +'</div>'+
            '<div class="score score_team1">'+
            '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="SCORE_APP.tools.setScore(\''+i+'\',\'up\')">'+
            '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/axk6J7M.jpg"/></a>'+
            '<span id="team_'+i+'_score">'+ data['team_'+i+'_score'] +'</span>'+
            '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="SCORE_APP.tools.setScore(\''+i+'\',\'dn\')">'+
            '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/movjGkd.jpg"/></a>'+
            '</div></div>';
      }    
      html += '</section>';
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;  
    }    
  },

  init : function(){
     this.game.gamePage(data); 
  }

};


SCORE_APP.init();
```

Add an ID to the `span` holding the score, and `onclick` send to the method `setScore` two arguments:

- the **team number** (i = 1||2)
- and the type of math we need to apply to the current score  <sub>(I used a string representation `"up"` and `"dn"`).</sub>

This two arguments are all you need to immediately keep up to date the `data` Object (holding the game stats) and apply the changes on screen to the targeted SPAN `ID`.

Comment: Perfect explanation! the only thing now is that the data is data from a json file. This data will be picked up from another method. So the getscore method can not reach my data.

Answer (score 0):

Set the onclick attribute within the `<a href="#" onclick="" ></a>` tag to calling a function such as increaseScore:

```
 onclick="increaseScore()"
```

And give the span element an id:

```
 <span id="myScore">
```

Then write a function which adds the score:

```
 function increaseScore()
 {
 score1++;
 document.getElementById("myScore").innerHTML=score1;
 }
```

Comment: Than I got the problem that i'm working with a Namespace and methods. If I add the function i will com back with the error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: increaseScore is not defined`. This is an example of an back button. So you can see an example

`html_back_button = '<a href="#" onclick="SCORE_APP.page.homePage()">Terug</a>';
            html = html + html_back_button;`